# MSSqlSM studio reacts really slowly

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is slow. And by slow I mean >1minute to render a context menu-slow.
All other things work perfectly fine. The connection to the database itself is not slow (my app works just fine and context menus don't need connection to the DB anyway I guess)..

Anybody has any idea what I should check to solve this?

**--EDIT--**

- Cpu is around 3%
- Gigs of free ram
- Only clicking right on a table in the object explorer, nothing else
- the database is remote
- It's the full version of SSMS
- No system logging errors
- Reinstall had no effect

**UPDATE**

I installed Toad for SQL and everything works super smooth there. Actually, I find it way more productive then MSSql ever was for me. It's not really an answer to my question, but it certainly a solution.

Comment: Are you connecting to a local or remote server?  How much ram do you have?  Express of full version?  What are you doing at the time in SSMS?

Comment: Is there anything in your Windows System or Application event logs?  Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling SSMS?  Have you got all of the latest drivers for your hardware?

Comment: Nothing I can find in the event logs (but I'm no sysadmin, so I might've overlooked something). Uninstalling/Reinstalling would be the verry last thing I would want to do, it takes ages.
My hardware/drivers is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed any add-ins/plugins? Those might be the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this behavior occur for all SQL Servers you connect to, or just a few in particular? If it's only certain ones, it may be a really slow SQL Server - to get any context menus or list databases, it has to execute some queries against the remote servers to collect information, and if they're less than responsive, SSMS will be too.